# Why is my N Queens algorithm reaching the last row?

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

I think I understand the point of the NQueens algorithm - you check each row for available spaces and if they exist, put a queen there, and recursively call the algorithm to the next row. Here is my algorithm (with N size 3)

```
from typing import List
import pdb
class Solution:
    def solveNQueens(self, n: int) -> List[List[str]]:
        self.solutions = 0 
        self.attack_zone = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]
        self.size = n
        self.backtrack_nqueens(0,0) #start on row 0 
        return self.solutions
    def backtrack_nqueens(self,row,iteration):
        #starting at row
        for col in range(self.size):
            if self.is_not_under_attack(row,col):
                print("on iteration",iteration,row,col,"was a safe place for some reason")
                #adds queen to this row
                self.place_or_remove_queen(row,col,True)
                if row + 1 == self.size:
                    ## THIS SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN 
                    self.solutions += 1
                else:
                    self.backtrack_nqueens(row+1,iteration+1)
                #removes queen from this row
                self.place_or_remove_queen(row,col,False)

    def place_or_remove_queen(self,row,col,place):
        flag = 1 if place else 0 
        self.attack_zone[row] = [flag]*self.size
        #for col
        for r in range(self.size):
            self.attack_zone[r][col] = flag
        #lower right
        for r,c in zip(range(row,self.size,1),range(col,self.size,1)):
            self.attack_zone[r][c] = flag
        #upper right
        for r,c in zip(range(row,-1,-1),range(col,self.size,1)):
            self.attack_zone[r][c] = flag
        #lower left
        for r,c in zip(range(row,self.size,1),range(col,-1,-1)):
            self.attack_zone[r][c] = flag
        #upper left
        for r,c in zip(range(row,-1,-1),range(col,-1,-1)):
            self.attack_zone[r][c] = flag

    def is_not_under_attack(self,row,col):
        return self.attack_zone[row][col] == 0
s = Solution()
print(s.solveNQueens(3))
```

When I run this, self.solutions ends up at 3 - basically it finds 3 places for a queen which we all know shouldn't happen. I don't understand how its getting to that row where I said ##THIS SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN.

The only thing I can think of is that I am somehow removing a queen that shouldn't be removed? So my attack_zone has empty spaces when it shouldn't. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong in the recursion that would cause this and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you remove a queen, you mark the corresponding squares as "free", i.e. setting their "threat count" to zero, regardless of whether another queen also threatens that square. Considering your example the following happens:

```
# Iteration 1     # Iteration 2     # Iteration 3

| 1 | 1 | Q |     | 1 | 1 | Q |     | 0 | 0 | Q |
+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+     +---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 1 |     | Q | 1 | 1 |     | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+     +---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 1 |     | 1 | 1 | 1 |     | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

On iteration #3 the queen on `(1, 0)` is removed and all corresponding squares are flagged as `0`, also the ones that are actually threatened by the queen on `(0, 2)`. The same happens for queens on `(1, 1)` and `(1, 2)` and the latter eventually leads to a free square on `(2, 0)` which is the last row.

In order to make the algorithm work you can maintain a "threat count" which tracks by how many queens a square is threatened. Placing a queen increases that count by one and removing a queen reduces it by one. You can realize this by changing the value of `flag` to `flag = 1 if place else -1` and then use `self.attack_zone[r][c] += flag` everywhere instead of `self.attack_zone[r][c] = flag`. This gives then the following picture:

```
# Iteration 1     # Iteration 2     # Iteration 3

| 1 | 1 | Q |     | 2 | 2 | Q |     | 1 | 1 | Q |
+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+     +---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 1 |     | Q | 2 | 2 |     | 0 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+     +---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 1 |     | 2 | 1 | 1 |     | 1 | 0 | 1 |
```